# how to perform three stage filtering of $scope in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I would like to perform a 3 stage filter on my $scope, for example:
[image]

So firstly user would choose a Course code which would narrow the results down, then 
[image]

the next select box (Occurrence) would filter the results of the first (Course Code)
[image]

And finally the last select box (Tutor group name) would filter the previously filtered remaining results and display them. What would be the correct angular way of achieving this please?

Comment: You can just chain filters: `ng-repeat="item in items | filter:course | filter: occurence | filter: groupName"`

Comment: thanks @devqon thats great I didnt know that :)